# Summing up all time periods

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where there are two columns that contain `time_from` and `time_to` of a particular event. Both columns' type is TINYINT(2). For eaxmple

```
id    time_from    time_to
__________________________
11       8            14
18       12           17    
44       20           24
```

Some periods overlap. I need to sum-up all time and make sure I do not double-count overlapped time.

Unfortunately I cannot change the column type and must work with what I've got. How can I do this?

The expected result is something like this:

```
14 - 8 = 6
17 - 12 = 5
24-20 = 4
```

Overlap is 2 hrs (12 - 14)

Total: 6 + 5 + 4 - 2 = 13

Comment: So what is the expected output with that you've shown here? `6 + 5 + 4` or `6 + 2 + 4` (ignore 12, 13, and 14 because id 11 contains it)? or something else?

Comment: @chris85 I've updated my post. I do want to count 12, 13 14 but only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your `time_from` and `time_to` columns represent hours in the range 1 to 24.

**Edit**. As you clarified, I'm assuming 20, 24 covers four hours, that is, 20, 21, 22, 23. Each range excludes the final hour mentioned: `[20,24)`.

You can solve this problem with a sequence table.  This is it. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57cf7f/4/0)

```
      SELECT 1 seq 
        UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5
        UNION ALL SELECT 6  UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL SELECT 9
        UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL SELECT 13
        UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15 UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17
        UNION ALL SELECT 18 UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
        UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23 UNION ALL SELECT 24
```

In MariaDB, it's built in: the table   `seq_1_to_24` is it.

Join it with your other table like this, and you get one row for each hour in each row of your other table.  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57cf7f/9/0)

```
SELECT seq.seq, t.*
  FROM (
          SELECT 1 seq UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5
                       UNION ALL SELECT 6  UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL SELECT 9
                       UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL SELECT 13
                       UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15 UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17
                       UNION ALL SELECT 18 UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
                       UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23 UNION ALL SELECT 24
        ) seq
   JOIN times t ON seq.seq >= t.time_from 
               AND seq.seq <  t.time_to
```

Finally, summarize that with `COUNT(DISTINCT seq) hours` and you get the number of hours that appear in one or more of the time intervals in your original table. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57cf7f/10/0)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT seq) hours
FROM (
SELECT seq.seq, t.*
  FROM (
          SELECT 1 seq UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5
                       UNION ALL SELECT 6  UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL SELECT 9
                       UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL SELECT 13
                       UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15 UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17
                       UNION ALL SELECT 18 UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
                       UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23 UNION ALL SELECT 24
        ) seq
   JOIN times t ON seq.seq >= t.time_from 
               AND seq.seq <  t.time_to
 ) a
```

Here's what it looks like in MariaDB.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT seq) hours
FROM (
SELECT seq.seq
  FROM seq_1_to_24 seq
   JOIN times t ON seq.seq >= t.time_from 
               AND seq.seq <  t.time_to
 ) a
```

Comment: This is great! Hours 20 - 24 are start - end range, so it's only 4.

Comment: Your specification isn't clear about the hour of the day 00:00 - 00:59. My solution is certainly defective in the way it counts that hour. My sequence table may need a `0` in place of the `24`.  Lesson: importance of careful specification.

Comment: This is way above my skill level and is way too cool! Thanks. P.S> I've never heard about mariaDB but it seems quite impressive. Definitely a great idea to have your options known.

Comment: Way above your skill level before you asked the question, I think. Now it's at your skill level! You're welcome.  At any rate, when using SQL, think **sets** of data in the Venn sense.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution assumes that the `time_from` and `time_to` are both sorted ascending and that the overlaps occur only between adjacent rows:

```
# Without touching the `id` column, I create a sequential column `my_id`, assuming that the name of the  table is `times`:

alter table times add my_id int(3) not null after id;
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE times SET my_id = @count:= @count + 1;

# I use a temporary table `times2` that starts with the second row of the `times_from` column; Here, 9999 can be any large enough number:

create temporary table times2 as select my_id, time_from from times limit 1, 9999;

# Now I add a new column `time_end` to the original table. I update it with data from `time_from` column but 'shifted' by one row upwards:

alter table times add time_end int(2) not null;
update times a join times2 b on a.my_id = (b.my_id - 1) set a.time_end = b.time_from;

# Ensure that the value of `time_end` in the last row is not zero:

update times set time_end = time_to order by my_id desc limit 1;

# The required value is taken by using the minimum of columns `time_from` and `time_end`:

select sum(LEAST(time_to,time_end) - time_from) from times;

# Uncomment below to clean up just after getting the results:
    # alter table times drop column my_id;
    # alter table times drop column time_end;
```